Godot. Resources of TileMap disappear after copy pasting
I am working on a little game in Godot and I tried to create a new TileMap by altering a TileMap that I had already created. After copying and pasting the TileMap to a Node2D the resources of the original one just disappeared. Closing the Godot application helps to prevent this from the original TileMap, but how I can copy paste without messing up the original TileMap?
